# Crystal Transparency(Shadows)

Tags: blender

I'm having a really hard time getting the shadows the become transparent.  I've looked online and followed tutorials, but it's not working(See Below).

[image]

It may be a little difficult to see so you should look at it in a different window.

How do I add transparency to the shadow(color less saturated), in a way to make the light look like it goes through the crystals?

Comment: The term you should look for is [caustics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caustic_(optics)), when doing these type of shadows.

Comment: how about a close-up of the crystal shadows?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if your materials are set up correctly, but your floor mesh should have the Receive Transparent option (I'm supposing the object selected is one of the crystals)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to set the "Shadow Color" of the light that's set to cast the shadows. Check under the Shadow settings for a colour box.

The only drawback is that it changes the shadows for *all* objects in the scene. You might be able to use light groups or layers somehow to limit the shadow's effects, but I don't know how that would work.